# How to remove excess volume when building a COMSOL geometry

Tags: geometry, comsol

I'm having problems removing the blue colored volumes from my COMSOL geometry. I want to remove them in a way that the resulting pipe system doesn't have any holes in it. Another way to put it: I want to cut off the "excess pipe".

[image: My current COMSOL geometry]

I have tried all boolean operations COMSOL provides, but nothing seems to be useful to my problem. Which COMSOL tool can i use to achieve my geometry described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to achieve this using a combination of boolean operations. But generally, the easiest way is to unite the objects, split them along interior boundaries, and delete the excess volumes:

- Add a "Union" operation.
- Add all objects or the relevant subset to the "input objects" selection.
- Leave the option "Keep interior boundaries" checked (the default).
- Add a "Split" operation and select the union as input object.
- Add "Delete Entities" and select "Object" from "Geometric entity level".
- Select all excess volumes.

Obviously, the original objects all have to properly overlap for this to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what i was looking for.